# background threading in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am implementing camera facility in my app, which even captures user location. So, which type of background threading can be used in this scenario? So, that when user is capturing picture, the background thread need to run to capture location.

I thought EDT. Is it good way in long learn?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a background thread for this. You can open a thread and return to the EDT as explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/edt.html) but it's unnecessary.

The right approach is just to use a location listener e.g.:

```
public MyListener implements LocationListener {
    public void locationUpdated(Location location) {
        // update UI etc.
    }

    public void providerStateChanged(int newState) {
        // handle status changes/errors appropriately
    }
}
LocationManager.getLocationManager().setLocationListener(new MyListener());
```

Taken from https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/location/LocationManager.html